# Can someone explain this inequality transformation

Tags: exponentiation

I have seen this transformation but am not sure what laws are applied to achieve it.

$$
\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \leq 10^{-6} \Rightarrow2^{n+1} \geq 10^6.
$$

I feel it is related to $x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x}$ and hence removing the negative exponents from both sides flips the inequality?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $2^{n+1} \cdot 10^6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $2^{n+1}>0$ and $10^6>0$ we get
$$10^6\le 2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $2^{n+1}$ to get
$$1\le10^{-6}\cdot2^{n+1}$$
Then divide by $10^{-6}$ to get
$$10^6\le2^{n+1}$$
Note that the inequality will not flip because $2^{n+1}$ and $10^{-6}$ are both positive.